# How to get error message in JSON SCHEMA VALIDATION using EVERIT in java?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, everit

I am trying to validate a json schema against the json input.
I am using

> org.everit.json.schema-1.0.0.jar

My json input

> {
> "id": 200,
> "name": "Green Learner",
> "cost": 0
> }

My JSON SCHEMA .

```
    {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Youtube Channel",
    "description": "Youtube Channel for software development training",
    "type": "object",
     
    "properties": {
     
       "id": {
          "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
          "type": "integer"
       },
         
       "name": {
          "description": "Name of the the channle",
          "type": "string"
       },
         
       "cost": {
          "type": "number",
          "minimum": 100,
          "maximum":10000
       }
    },
     
    "required": ["id", "name", "cost"]
 }
```

JAVA Code for validation.

```
import org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;
import org.everit.json.schema.Schema;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

/**
 *
 * @author amitkumar
 */
public class JsonValidate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File schemaFile = new File("schema.json");

        JSONTokener schemaData = new JSONTokener(new FileInputStream(schemaFile));
        JSONObject jsonSchema = new JSONObject(schemaData);

        //json data
        File jsonData = new File("product_invalid.json");
        JSONTokener jsonDataFile = new JSONTokener(new FileInputStream(jsonData));
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonDataFile);

       
        Schema schemaValidator = SchemaLoader.load(jsonSchema);
        schemaValidator.validate(jsonObject);

        System.out.println(jsonObject.getInt("cost"));

    }
}
```

When i run the code with org.everit.json.schema-1.0.0.jar, i get following error message .

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.everit.json.schema.ValidationException:v0.0 is not higher or equal
> to 100

This is the warning message i get when i use

> json-schema-validator-1.0.42.jar comes with com.networknt it clearly mention me object name which got error.

```
$.Cost: 0.0 is not higher or equal to 100
```

i want to do the same with org.everit.json.schema-1.0.0.jar, which object in my json input got the error .It does not show me the object name .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64967960/how-to-customize-error-messages-for-jsonschema/65182639#65182639              This might help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize error messages for JSONSchema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64967960/how-to-customize-error-messages-for-jsonschema)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the library does not support your requirement, you could log the missing information by yourself. Something like

```
try {
    schemaValidator.validate(jsonObject);
} catch(ValidationException e) {
    LOG.error("Validation error in Object: '{}'", yourObjectName, e)
}
```

By the way, there are more newer versions than `1.0.0` of `org.everit.json.schema` available: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.everit.json/org.everit.json.schema

*Edit add additional information:*

The `ValidationException` has methods like `getPointerToViolation()` which might get you the information you need. See JavaDoc of the current version: https://erosb.github.io/everit-json-schema/javadoc/1.12.2/org/everit/json/schema/ValidationException.html#getPointerToViolation()

Be aware, that version `1.0.0` does not have this methods ([JavaDoc of v1.0.0](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.everit.json/org.everit.json.schema/1.0.0/index.html))!

Comment: But how will i know which object got the error .

Comment: I added additional information to my answer.